# VS2019 C++ unknown override specifier

Tags: c++, syntax, compiler-errors, include, visual-studio-2019

I have difficulties using VS2019 to compile my C++ code.

I have Person.h header file:

```
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H
#include <string>

using namespace std;

namespace PersonClass {

    struct Person {
    public:
        Name name;
        int age;
    };

    struct Name {
    public:
        string firstName;
        string lastName;

    };
}
#endif
```

And here is my main.cpp:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Person.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
return 0;
}
```

When I compile this file I got following error:

1. 'name': unknown override specifier missing type specifier - int
   assumed.
2. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Can someone teach me how to fix this problem?

Comment: Your compile is not a fortune-teller. It should know what `Name` is before you use it in `Name name;`.

Comment: Order matters! Things needs to be declared before they are used.

Comment: You should define `Person` first, and then define `Name`

Answer (score 3):

`struct Name` has not yet been defined when you attempt to make use of it. Define `struct Name` *before* you define `struct Person`.